# May one use rice paper on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, modern-times

May one use rice paper on Shabbos?

Rice paper is made by mixing the water and starch left over from cooking rice with tapioca starch and other ingredients and then spread into a thin layer which is then dried. The result is a thin plastic-like disc that when placed in warm water becomes moist again and can be used to make spring rolls, similar to sushi.

Is the reconstituting process permitted? Is erasing the simple designs on them permitted?

Comment: For those of us who have never "used" rice paper, can you [edit] to clarify what it is and what it is "used" for?

Comment: https://baisdovyosef.com/1603-the-rise-of-the-rice/